Tracking extract - attributes file
can someone help with including attributes in the tracking extract output?
My goal is to include in the tracking extract an internal list id that corresponds with a subscribers' event. That list id is added to the file generated by our EDW then imported into a DE.
I select "Extract Attributes" then define the attribute I want included in the free-form field.  When I run the extract I get the Attributes file and the attribute I've defined is the column header, but the column is empty.
What I'm looking for is to include that attribute in the other files in the extract to then be ingested into our EDW for reporting purposes. So for example each record that was sent would have an "InternalListID" attribute column and the column would pull the InternalListID from the DE and append it to the file; same for bounces, opens, clicks.
Based on the Tracking Extract and Attributes documentation, I feel like that should be the expected outcome, but so far it is not. Am I doing something wrong or is that functionality not what I think it is.

Can you confirm the attribute is indeed stored as part of the Subscriber, similar to the scenario described here?

@LukasLunow it is not, it's an attribute in the data extension I'm sending to. I take it including attributes in the tracking extract only applies to list attributes?

That is correct. And not just from any list, but Subscriber Attributes, which reside on the All Subscribers list. What you could consider, is to use a Send Log. Assuming the internal list ID is always a field on your sendable data extension, you could store it in the sendlog and export this as well. This will allow you to join details on the send ("Internal list ID", Subscriber Key, Job ID, Batch ID, etc.) from the send log, with details stored in tracking extract.

@LukasLunow thank you, that's what I'll do.

Added this as an answer for added visibility

As the attribute in Tracking Extract needs to be a Subscriber attribute, it is not sufficient only to have it available as a field on the sendable data extension.
What you could consider, is to use a Send Log. Assuming the internal list ID is always a field on your sendable data extension, you could store it in the sendlog and export this as well. This will allow you to join details on the send ("Internal list ID", Subscriber Key, Job ID, Batch ID, etc.) from the send log, with details stored in tracking extract. Joining can then be done on these send specific IDs (Job ID etc.)
